# How to use Guvnor REST API to GET an Excel file?

Tags: excel, cxf, drools, guvnor

Can anyone advise on the correct class type to pass as a parameter to the Guvnor REST API if I want to get a deployed Excel file from Guvnor?

```
> WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/"); 
> client.header("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
> client.path("jboss-brms/rest/packages/PR/assets/ARule/binary").accept("application/octet-stream").get(FileInputStream.class);
```

The code above is giving me:

*javax.ws.rs.client.ClientException: .Problem with reading the response message, class : class java.io.FileInputStream, ContentType : application/octet-stream.
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.reportMessageHandlerProblem(AbstractClient.java:744)

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
       at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2990)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider.readFrom(BinaryDataProvider.java:67)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1288)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:506)*

I'm using Apache CXF2.7.6 and jdk1.6.0_37

Comment: Sorry, got it working with InputStream.class. No further issue now.

Comment: What was the problem? What was the solution? Please answer your own question and mark if as a correct answer, if you think it could be useful information to anyone else. Otherwise I think the question should be removed.